# Manga or manhwa about a guy moving to Korea

Tags: very-very-sweet

I remember reading this, but I didn't finish it. I think there was only a few chapters at the time. This is what I remember.

There is a boy who is Japanese. However, he found out from a family member that he had Korean blood and he needed to move to Korea for some reason.

When he got to Korea, I think he shared a taxi with a Korean girl OR the girl came with someone to pick him up from the airport as he was staying with her family.

The both of them didn't like each other. I remember the boy complaining that Koreans are loud, and when they got out the car, I think the girl spat on him.

I might be wrong about his nationality and where he moves to. If so then swap the Korean parts with the Japanese parts.

Thanks a lot! I really want to read this again.

Comment: anything else you remember? like any trails how they look like?

Answer (score 3):

It's [Very, Very Sweet!](http://myanimelist.net/manga/5287/Very!_Very!_Sweet)

Or, it is if I recall correctly.

I actually had volume one, but lost it -- and I was looking it up [what you put] on google images and BAM-

[image: cover!]

the cover!

> The Japanese boy, Tsuyoshi, is a restless troublemaker whose severely strict grandfather has finally been given the reins to crack down on him. His grandfather sends him on a quest to find the roots of their ancestry. The family names' roots brings him to Korea where his taxi driver, a chatty energetic girl named Very (Be-Ri), passes out on him. Despite an ugly first encounter, the two later grow close and learn to respect each other's differences...

Comment: Could you format the answer a little bit? Also a synapsis would be nice. :3